# Что изменить в коде jquery по обработке чекбоксов?

Tags: jquery

Приветствую, собственно нужна небольшая помощь или совет, есть скрипт по обработке нестандартного `checkbox`, он рабочий. Мне надо изменить его функционал так, что бы отмечались/снимались отметки с нескольких чекбоксов, сейчас это происходит просто:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').css({
  'opacity': 0
});

$('input[type=checkbox]').css({
  'opacity': 0
}).wrap('<span class="wrap-checkbox"></span>');

$('.wrap-checkbox').click(function() {
  $('.wrap-checkbox').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

при клике на определенный `checkbox` (точнее, его обертку), ему присваивается класc `active`, и соответственно - он активный (отмечен). При клике на следующий, предыдущий автоматически делается не активным. Как исправить, чтобы этого не происходило, чтобы можно было отметить несколько `checkbox` или наоборот снять с них выделение? Знаю что просто, но в голову ничего не приходит. Помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените последние строки на следующий код:

```
$('.wrap-checkbox').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```